# Deploy Node, Express, and MongoDB server to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I created a server using Node, Express, and MongoDB Atlas. Here is the code of this:

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

// model
let Cards = require('./models/cards.model');

// App config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


// DB config
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection has been established successfully.");
})


// API Endpoints

// POST parameter
app.post('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
    const card = req.body;

    Cards.create(card, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
})

// GET parameter
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send("Welcome to Tinder Clone Backend with NodeJS, ExpressJS, and MongoDB!!!")
})

app.get('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
    Cards.find((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
});

// Listener
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tinder-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2"
  }
}
```

**cards.model.js**

```
// creating database schema using mongoose

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const cardsSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    imgUrl: String
});



const Cards = mongoose.model('Cards', cardsSchema);

module.exports = Cards;
```

It is working locally and all endpoints sending and receiving data from mongodb atlas.
when I run this command in terminal to start the local server:
**$ nodemon server**

it is showing this:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is running on port 5000
MongoDB database connection has been established successfully.
```

This means that my local server is running well and when I check in my browser and type in my server link i.e **http://localhost:5000/tinder/cards**, it showing data that I have posted previously:

```
[
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f2",
"name": "Elon Musk",
"imgUrl": "https://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Elon-Musk-AP.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f3",
"name": "Shakira",
"imgUrl": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/738B/production/_116497592_gettyimages-971720370.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f4",
"name": "Jeff Bezos",
"imgUrl": "https://media.wired.com/photos/6019cab23453f789506008d0/master/pass/Sec_Bezos_1036084400.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f5",
"name": "Dua Lipa",
"imgUrl": "https://assets.vogue.com/photos/5f48136693122510d16f0352/4:3/w_1080,h_810,c_limit/118520052_586967341971321_6121798062289952442_n.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f6",
"name": "Pitbull",
"imgUrl": "https://vz.cnwimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Pitbull.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f7",
"name": "Ellen",
"imgUrl": "https://www.geo.tv/assets/uploads/updates/2021-03-18/340307_5260100_updates.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f8",
"name": "Bill Gates",
"imgUrl": "https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1920x1080/getty_1185999101_20001333200092800_443629.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4f9",
"name": "Taylor Swift",
"imgUrl": "https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/12/02/taylor-swift1.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4fa",
"name": "Engin Altan",
"imgUrl": "https://www.incpak.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/50094085_2224186024567959_693900883193935752_n.jpg",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "605a53881dedb514dcc1c4fb",
"name": "Esra Bilgic",
"imgUrl": "https://i.dawn.com/large/2021/01/6007fbceb61de.png",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

But when I deployed the same server to heroku, it is showing an empty object when I testing it.

When I run this command into my terminal:
**$ heroku logs --tails**

It is showing this error:

```
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715303+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to
any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.
 Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715323+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:839:32)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715324+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:348:10
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715326+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715326+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715327+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715328+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1152:10)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715328+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:347:20)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715329+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:23:10)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715329+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715329+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715330+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715330+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715331+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715331+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-03-25T11:08:08.715332+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.721117+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated
either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To term
inate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html
#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-03-25T11:08:08.721508+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the fut
ure, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

my server that is deployed on heroku is showing empty object instead of that data that I have posted,
when I type URL of heroku server i.e **https://tinder-clone-backend-mern.herokuapp.com/tinder/cards** :

```
{}
```

How can I make this server work perfectly as the local server does?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IPS, in your Atlas cluster/Network Access, to be available for all IPS (0.0.0.0/0) Let me know if it fixes.

Comment: I already checked it, it is showing the same error.

Comment: Do you have a Procfile file in your root app? and also you have to add a Script - Start - Command of start app in your package.json. Do you have all of it?

Comment: I neither have Procfile file in my root app nor command of start in package.json

Comment: const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI; process.env belongs to heroku, you can't set your db options in that way. Write them as plain text in your files.